# kubectl: Unsuccessful API Version Negotiation (google-kubernetes-engine)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm facing difficulties while trying to access one of my Kubernetes. I encounter an error message stating the following  whenever I execute the `kubectl` command:

> `error: failed to negotiate an API version`

Could someone help me comprehend what could have gone wrong?

Despite my efforts to troubleshoot this problem, I've been unable to resolve the issue on my own.

Comment: you will get the above error when kubectl tool version mismatch.  Kindly check skew policy https://kubernetes.io/releases/version-skew-policy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running kubectl command and you are getting an error: failed to negotiate an api version because  this command needs to be authenticated.

Follow the two workarounds and have a try  :

- As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#failed_to_negotiate) ,  you need to Ensure kubectl has authentication
  credentials:

```
       gcloud auth application-default login
```

- You can also try below  :

```
       Install the gcloud beta component (gcloud components install beta)
       Run gcloud beta auth application-default login
      After that, the kubectl version will work.
```

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) for more information